# Stopping Script for x seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I am new to actions script and I want to stall the code itself for just a bit, but all the tutorials and libraries I have looked at seems to focus more on stopping the Movie clip. Also seems that you have to call a function with a timer, but I just purely want it to wait a few seconds.

What I want to achieve:

Want a function to finish before continuing to the next function.

The Code: 
(Credit for code goes to Garry Law. Using his code to provide better clarity)

```
    function PlayGame() {
       PauseThenDisplayText(1,"Get Ready");
       PauseThenDisplayText(1,"Get Ready");
    }

    function PauseThenDisplayText(sec,txt) {
        trace('timer starts');
        var timer1:Timer = new Timer (sec*1000,1);
        timer1.start();  
        timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
        function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void{
            trace('timer event triggered');
            timer1.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
            Display_Screen.text = txt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason your code won't work is because the code is all being read before your timer ends. You'll need to add listeners to the Timer event. For example:

```
function PlayGame() {
    PauseThenDisplayText1(1);
}

function PauseThenDisplayText1(sec) {
    trace('timer starts 1');
    var timer1:Timer = new Timer (sec*1000,1);
    timer1.start();  
    timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
    function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void{
        trace('timer event triggered 1');
        timer1.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
        Display_Screen.text = "Get Ready";

        //now that first timer finishes, start next one
        PauseThenDisplayText2(1);
    }
}

function PauseThenDisplayText2(sec) {
    trace('timer starts 2');
    var timer2:Timer = new Timer (sec*1000,1);
    timer2.start();  
    timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
    function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void{
        trace('timer event triggered 2');
        timer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
        Display_Screen.text = "Start Game";
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this but it actually didn't work, since both timers are start at roughly the same time. Meaning I never see the "get ready". Again looking for a way to pause the script from going to the second timer.

PauseThenDisplayText(1,"Get Ready"). 
Pause thenDisplayText(1,"Start").

I am going to edit the code above for clarity to toher reades using the code you have provided if that is ok with you?

Comment: feel free. I've updated the code to show how you'd make the 2 calls